# How to remove the gray overlay on top of the Video in firefox using the new HTML5 <video>?

Tags: html, html5-video

When viewing my web page in Firefox 31 on windows 7, the `video` tag shows a picture of the video first frame with dark/gray overlay. The video works with no problem. I'd like it to show without this gray/dark color on it (the color goes away once the video is played).

When viewing the same page on Chrome 36 or IE , the image is white and there is no gray color on it.  Here is screen shot of the same page to illustrate

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The HTML code uses is

```
 <video width="300" height="240" controls>
     <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm"> <!-bright on chrome,dark on FF-->
    <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
     <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
```

Is there a way, using css or otherwise, to make the look the same as on Chrome above. It is better to be able to more clearly see the screen shot before clicking play, and having dark gray shadow does not look nice.

This is all on windows 7, 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is mush to do with it. But you can display some thumbnail of this image, when clicking on it, replace thumbnail with real video and auto-play it.

Comment: Have you actually tried it yourself? Using a `poster="image"` has no effect at all on removing the gray color from the top of the image. All what it does is change the image below the gray shadow. But you are welcome to try it and show me how it actually removes the gray shadow on top. This is what I tried `<video width="320" height="auto" controls poster="myImage.png">` Unless there is a different way to do this. But you did not say how to do it.

Comment: @Nasser I mean something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Justinas_Jurciukonis/rzyejnoa/1/, just make it auto-start after click

Comment: Thank you for the example, but this does not solve the issue. First of all, the gray box is still there, but now it is empty. So might as well use the `POSTER="image"` option, much simpler, and shows an image there under the gray box. Much better than having an empty gray box. The issue the the gray box, which your solution does not remove. I am looking for a solution to remove the gray box that firefox shows before starting the video. May be there is no solution, which is fine. I accept that. But your solution does not remove the gray box. Sorry. Thanks again for trying.

Comment: @Nasser did you ever solve this? I'm having the same issue and the internet has almost nothing to say about it.

Comment: @skybondsor  I do not see this now on latest firefox. You can check an example here [here](http://12000.org/my_notes/mma_demos/bouncing_ball/play_movie.htm) and look at the HTML course to see if it any help. The main page the above is linked to is [here](http://12000.org/my_notes/mma_demos/index.htm) may be this will help.