# How do I remove the following HTML5 video element control in Firefox?

Tags: css, html, html5-video

I am having an issue in Firefox specifically where my  elements, before being played, have a bright grey play button overlay over the poster attribute image:

[image: ff yt]

Versus in Chrome and IE where the player appears as such:

[image: chrome/ie yt]

My HTML is basic:

```css
main {
  width: 75%;
  height: 700px;
  padding-right: 1.9%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

video {
  margin-left: 9.2%;
  margin-top: 11%;
  border: 4px solid black;
  object-fit: initial;
}


/*Causes the poster to not leave gaps between itself and the border*/
```

```html
<video id="video" width="768" height="432" poster="img/main/intro1poster.png" controls>
        <source src="media/videos/intro1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video or Flash. 
           A low quality version of the video can be found here: <br/>
           <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BDw7xpzH-68">Dev Update #1</a></p>
</video>
```

This question has been asked in 1 other thread two years ago ([How to remove the gray overlay on top of the Video in firefox using the new HTML5 <video>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25243630/how-to-remove-the-gray-overlay-on-top-of-the-video-in-firefox-using-the-new-html)) that I can find, but no solution was ever presented. I am willing to use javascript in the solution, but I do not want to completely redesign the controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default controls UI of Firefox. We still don't have any way to modify it ourselves in this browser, so you are tied to two options :

- [Create your own controls UI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/cross_browser_video_player).
  This will allow you to have a consistent and fully customizable UI across all browsers.
- Use of some hacks that may break in future (or even in past)

Here is one such hack that I only tested on FF 54 :

This overlay disappears whenever you start playing the video.
By setting the video's `autoplay` attribute, we can then get rid of it. But you need to call its `pause()` method as soon as possible to avoid the actual playing of the video.

```js
// pause it as soon as possible
document.getElementById('video').pause();
```

```css
video {
  margin-left: 9.2%;
  margin-top: 11%;
  border: 4px solid black;
  object-fit: initial;
}
```

```html
<video id="video" width="768" height="432" poster="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg/800px-John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg" controls autoplay>
  <!-- simply added 'autoplay' attribute -->
  <source src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/bch2j17v6ny4ako/movie720p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: This worked beautifully. I simply used the javascript inline placing the script element immediately following the video element:
`<script>document.getElementById('dev_video').pause();</script>`

Comment: @JohnJames, but beware this is an hack. It will force the preloading of the video, and may break anytime in future release (seems ok until at least 56 though). The first option is definitely the best one.